# How to declare a function that accepts a lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I read on the internet many tutorials that explained how to use lambdas with the standard library (such as `std::find`), and they all were very interesting, but I couldn't find any that explained how I can use a lambda for my own functions.

For example:

```
int main()
{
    int test = 5;
    LambdaTest([&](int a) { test += a; });

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How should I declare `LambdaTest`? What's the type of its first argument? And then, how can I call the anonymous function passing to it - for example - "10" as its argument?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Given that you probably also want to accept function pointers and function objects in addition to lambdas, you'll probably want to use templates to accept any argument with an `operator()`. This is what the std-functions like find do. It would look like this:

```
template<typename Func>
void LambdaTest(Func f) {
    f(10);
}
```

Note that this definition doesn't use any c++0x features, so it's completely backwards-compatible. It's only the call to the function using lambda expressions that's c++0x-specific.

Comment: In case of errors the error messages will be difficult to understand.

Comment: It depends whether it's the best. This uses a template, and the other doesn't. This means that the function can't be virtual anymore and can't be defined separately in the cpp file. `std::function` is perfectly able to take function object class types too, albeit is a little slower when calling. But that difference is negligible for the very most applications :)

Comment: "best" is in the eye of the beholder :-) this answer uses a `functor` which is nice, but does not really answer the original question (and what led me here) which was "how do I use a lambda for my own functions".  Also, templates have their own set of issues, which the answer with `std::function` doesn't.

Comment: @Marco This answer doesn't require you to use functiors, it allows you to use whatever you want - including lambdas.

Comment: Who is enforcing the fact that the function gets an int as an argument? Being more generic sometimes lead to errors.

Answer (score 91):

If you don't want to template everything, you can do the following:

```
#include<functional> 

void LambdaTest (const std::function <void (int)>& f)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This syntax actually allows me to save the function variable to call it later, right? For example I wanted to implement a function that allowed to execute asynchronous database queries, where the lambda acts as a callback. (Of course I wouldn't be able to access closures by reference)

Comment: Isn't it more idiomatic to pass functions by value?

Comment: @Andreas Bonini: Yes, if you save to `std::function` (not a reference), you make a copy of `f`.  However, I'm not sure how lambda/closures handle references when the object referred to goes out of scope, probably UB.
@FredOverflow: My understanding is that `std::function` is not a trivial object, especially when wrapping lambdas.  It is probably better to reference it to avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: If your lambda captures the stack by value then yes the lambda can outlive those variables and will continue to keep copies of them. If it captures by reference you will have a problem.

Comment: We will have to copy it inside the function, so there is no point copying it as it is passed in

Answer (score 10):

I would like to contribute this simple but self-explanatory example. It shows how to pass "callable things" (functions, function objects, and lambdas) to a function or to an object.

```
// g++ -std=c++11 thisFile.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------
class Box {
public:
  function<void(string)> theFunction; 
  bool funValid;

  Box () : funValid (false) { }

  void setFun (function<void(string)> f) {
    theFunction = f;
    funValid = true;
  }

  void callIt () {
    if ( ! funValid ) return;
    theFunction (" hello from Box ");
  }
}; // class

// -----------------------------------------------------------------
class FunClass {
public:
  string msg;
  FunClass (string m) :  msg (m) { }
  void operator() (string s) {
    cout << msg <<  s << endl; 
  }
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------
void f (string s) {
  cout << s << endl;
} // ()

// -----------------------------------------------------------------
void call_it ( void (*pf) (string) ) {
  pf( "call_it: hello");
} // ()

// -----------------------------------------------------------------
void call_it1 ( function<void(string)> pf ) {
  pf( "call_it1: hello");
} // ()

// -----------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {

  int a = 1234;

  FunClass fc ( " christmas ");

  f("hello");

  call_it ( f );

  call_it1 ( f );

  // conversion ERROR: call_it ( [&] (string s) -> void { cout << s << a << endl; } );

  call_it1 ( [&] (string s) -> void { cout << s << a << endl; } );

  Box ca;

  ca.callIt ();

  ca.setFun (f);

  ca.callIt ();

  ca.setFun ( [&] (string s) -> void { cout << s << a << endl; } );

  ca.callIt ();

  ca.setFun (fc);

  ca.callIt ();

} // ()
```

Comment: You don't need funValid : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool, just say `if ( ! theFunction )`