# C++ Defining a function which works with lambda closures

Tags: c++, lambda, closures

I have a problem figuring out a lambda function definition. So I have this code, which is working properly:

```
auto fnClickHandler = [](Button *button) -> void
{
    cout << "click" << endl;
};
button->setEventHandler(MOUSEBUTTONUP, fnClickHandler);
```

However I need to use a closure inside fnClickHandler, so I do this code:

```
int someParam = 1;

auto fnClickHandler = [someParam](Button *button) -> void
{
    cout << "click" << someParam << endl;
};
button->setEventHandler(MOUSEBUTTONUP, fnClickHandler);
```

And now I get the following compile error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘Button::setEventHandler(BUTTON_EVENT_HANDLERS, nameOfFunctionWhichHostsThisCode::__lambda0&)’|
```

This is how the Button::setEventHandler function is defined:

```
void setEventHandler(int, void (*handler)(Button *));
```

I guess I need to change that definition to support lambda closure parameters (optional), but so far I'm failing. Can you help me figure it out?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare a function that accepts a lambda?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938571/how-to-declare-a-function-that-accepts-a-lambda)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Captureless lambdas can be implicitly converted to function pointers with the same signature. That is why your code worked with the no-capture version of `fnClickHandler`. Once you have a capturing lambda, you have two options :

1. Create a function template and let the compiler deduce the type for you

   ```
   template <typename Handler>
   void setEventHandler(int, Handler handler);//You can use either enable_if or static_assert to restrict the types of Handler.
   ```
2. Use an [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

   ```
   void setEventHandler(int, std::function<void(Button *)>);
   ```

Comment: TYPO ahead! "tyepname" should be "typename". Good answer, though.