# c++ Declare function in parameters

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I want to declare a function directly in the parameters like this from C#:

```
var module = new Module(
    (object sender, Args a) => { return something; }
)
```

So I can call the variable in the class as a normal function.
What type needs the Module variable to be and how do I write a function to pass in C++?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938571/how-to-declare-a-function-that-accepts-a-lambda

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a function that accepts a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938571/how-to-declare-a-function-that-accepts-a-lambda)

Answer (score 0):

> What type needs the Module variable to be and how do I write a function to pass in C++?

I assume you are asking about the variable `module`, not the type `Module`.

When you use

```
var module = new Module(
    (object sender, Args a) => { return something; }
)
```

The type of `module` will be `Module*`.

You can use

```
 Module(
    (object sender, Args a) => { return something; }
    )
```

to construct a `Module` as long as it has a constructor that can accept the lambda function as an argument.

E.g.

```
struct Module
{
    template <typename L> Module(L l) { ... }
};
```

or

```
struct Module
{
    Module(std::function<R(object, Args)> f) { ... }
};
```

where `R` is the type of `something`.