# How to send lambda function as parameter to another function

Tags: c++

How to write "find" function definition if I have lambda as expression:

```
    int main() {
        vector<Student> v = { Student("Pero", "Peric", "3882"),
            Student("Ivo", "Ivic", "10991"),
            Student("Mara", "Maric", "40911"),
            Student("Ivan", "Juric", "93877"),
            Student("Ivo", "Kalic", "20991")
        };
vector<Student*> r = find(v, [](Student* s) { return s->name() == "Ivo"; });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a function that accepts a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938571/how-to-declare-a-function-that-accepts-a-lambda)

Comment: The idiomatic way is to use a template function. Something like `template <typename F> auto find(const std::vector<Student>& vec, F find) { ... }`.

Comment: Show the full code, but first, try searching please.

Comment: not related but I would call this find_all_if or something, find somewhat implied it would get one element not all of them (at least thats what standard library find does)

Comment: if `find` is `std::find_if` you should change `Student* s` to `const Student& s`

Comment: @Mestkon Even if it's not, since the elements are values, the function should take a reference, not a far less tidy pointer for no reason.

Comment: @underscore_d I agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype for a find function which accept your input :

```
vector<Student*> find(vector<Student> & v, std::function<bool(Student*)> lambdaFct)
```

Obviously except if your find call if the std::find. Your question isn't very clear.

Edit after next comment : 
Or template way :

```
template<typename Func>
vector<Student*> find(vector<Student> & v, Func f)
```

Comment: There is no point adding the overhead of using an `std::function` if the OP doesn't need to, i.e. if they can write template code to do the same thing without expensive type erasure. Not that it probably matters in practice either way, in this case... but one should write the simplest thing first and only complicate it later if there's concrete evidence that one needs to.

Comment: ...and the vector should probably be passed as `const` reference

Comment: The vector must be non-const if the return vector contains pointers to non-const students

Comment: @Mestkon thanks, yes it's why I made the input vector no-const.

Comment: And the `Func` should be passed by Universal reference in case it has data that is expensive to copy.  `template<typename Func> vector<Student*> find(vector<Student> & v, Func&& f)`